# How to insert data to Json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi I am trying to learn json and I am a total biginner I will really apprieciate any advice. Thank you.

I have a json file name file1.json that has some content below

```
{
    "name": "Example object",
    "lastname": "asdfgh"
}

{
    "name": "Example object2",
    "lastname": "asdfgh2wer"
}
```

Then I have html that will require to input name and last name I want every time they click submit button the data that been be inputted will be store in the 
file1.json my code is below name "Form1.html" however it is not adding anything to json file

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

form div {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
form div label, form div input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

</style>
<form id="test" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <label for="name">Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
    </p>
</form> 
<pre id="output"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    function toJSONString( form ) {
        var obj = {};
        var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input");
        for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var name = element.name;
            var value = element.value;

            if( name ) {
                obj[ name ] = value;
            }
        }

        return JSON.stringify( obj );
    }

    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var form = document.getElementById( "test" );
        var output = document.getElementById( "output" );
        form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var json = toJSONString( this );
            output.innerHTML = json;
            localStorage.setItem('user.json', JSON.stringify(json));

        }, false);

    });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: Its not adding in the file1.json the data that i input in the form.

Comment: I see nothing here that "adds to a json file". I think your misunderstanding what [localstorage is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Your not going to be able to edit a file on your local machine using javascript, nor in reality is this very useful. I'd focus on doing something more practical.

Comment: ohh i see. but is there any other way to add the data that i input in the form to the json file?

Comment: Not really. Browsers have very limited access to the machine they are running on (for good reason). If you're doing this "for learning" you've wondered down a dead end.